# Comment transposer « to pull shenanigans » dans un contexte informel ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, locutions, langage-informel

> We're the two largest trading partners anywhere in the world. It's
>   like one of your family members [says], 'OK, you go starve, and we'll
>   go feast on the rest of the meal.' I'm just so disappointed right
>   now...
>
> We have a great relationship with the U.S., and they **[pull](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pull) these
>   [shenanigans](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shenanigans#English)**? Unacceptable.
>
> [ Le Premier ministre de l'Ontario, Doug Ford, sur [cbc.ca](https://www.cbc.ca/news/coronavirus-covid-19-1.5522437) ]

[Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/shenanigans/611204) en ligne parle de *manigances* ou *combines* ; [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/shenanigan#en) parle de *magouille, manigance, grenouillage*. L'emploi du verbe *to pull* vaut pour *to do/perform* dans ce contexte, comme dans « you'll be sent home if you pull another stunt like that » (Wiktionnaire) mais ce serait d'un registre informel (Wiktionnaire). Dans le contexte de la citation, « s'adonner à de telles magouilles » m'apparaît inadéquat, je le trouve trop formel, en particulier le verbe.

Comment peut-on transposer la locution verbale « to pull shenanigans » de sorte que ce soit naturel en français dans un tel contexte d'exaspération, de critique, de franc-parler ?

Comment: Svp dans vos solutions pensez à définir la locution ou le terme que vous employez et à expliquer l'adéquation avec la locution en langue anglaise ou ce que vous en comprennez à partir de la question. Merci !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Une formule un peu éloignée du sens de l'anglais mais qui me semble assez proche de l'idée attendue :

> ...et ils nous plantent un couteau dans le dos !

Aussi :

> ...et ils nous sortent un coup tordu comme ça !

Answer (score 2):

« Nous avons une très bonne relation avec les Etats-Unis, et ils se livrent à ce genre de micmac.  C'est inacceptable ! »

Answer (score 1):

[Mesquinerie](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/mesquin/50762?q=Mesquin#50655) pourrait convenir dans le sens où "pulling shenanigans" évoque pour moi de la petitesse plus que du machiavélisme.

> ... avec les États-Unis, et ils inventent ce genre de mesquinerie. C'est inacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Quelques idées supplémentaires sur le thème de « [l'idée attendue](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/41653) ». [*Jouer*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jouer) en emploi pronominal réfléchi comme dans *se jouer de quelqu'un* signifiant *tromper* est plutôt littéraire ([Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/se_jouer/45012?q=se%20jouer#44962)). Mais on a *jouer quelqu'un* pour *duper* (TLFi).

> ...et ils essayent de nous jouer/de se jouer de nous ?

Dans Larousse en ligne anglais-français on trouve à [*game*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/game/582772) signifiant *scheme, trick* en langage informel « two can play at that game! / moi aussi je peux jouer à ce petit jeu-là ». Or en décomposant le tout on trouve que *jouer à ce petit jeu-là* peut être utile seul, pour évoquer *(faire tel) procédé douteux* [semble-t-il](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/65349). On rejoint peut-être l'idée de petitesse dont on traite dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/41657) ; j'ai l'impression que l'adjectif *petit* ajoute un aspect péjoratif au *jeu* :

> ...et ils décident de jouer à ce petit jeu-là ?

En explorant les [synonymes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shenanigans#Synonyms) reliés à *deceitful tricks* comme *dirty tricks, hornswoggling, skulduggery* on trouve rapidement [*entourloupette*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/dirty_trick), familier, et une référence au verbe [*entourlouper*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entourloupette) signifiant *duper par tromperie* (TLFi). On a aussi *sale coup*, rappelant ce qu'on trouve dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/41653). C'est sans compter l'entourloupette dans le domaine des affaires pour l'*irrégularité, tromperie* et on présente le synonyme *tour de passe-passe* (TLFi) ; je pense que ce serait employé avec le verbe *faire*. Quant à skulduggery, on trouve dans l'univers dénombrable le terme [*stratagème*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/stratag%C3%A8me), pas inutile, que j'emploierais avec *faire dans* sur le modèle de *faire dans la finesse*, *ne pas faire dans la dentelle* :

> ...et ils essayent de nous entourlouper, de nous faire un tour de
>   passe-passe ? 
>     ...et ils ne pensent qu'à faire dans le stratagème ?

De fil en aiguille, on a en régionalisme (Québec), tout d'abord, la locution [*passer un sapin*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/passer_un_sapin) signifiant *escroquer, tromper* (Wiktionnaire). On peut aussi substituer *crosse* à sapin pour *fraude, arnaque* ; on omet le verbe (se faire) [*crosser*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/crosser), vulgaire, et (se faire) [*fourrer*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fourrer), davantage encore :

> ...et ils essayent de nous passer un sapin/une crosse ?

Enfin je note que *simagrées* peut valoir pour le geste utilisé pour tromper ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/simagr%C3%A9e), [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/simagr%C3%A9e#fr) : quoique dans l'[exemple](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_War_in_the_Air/Chapter_IX) de H.G. Wells ça servait à traduire *antics* dans un autre contexte ; *les pitreries, le cirque* nous dit [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/antics/562627)...). Par ailleurs on a *de cirque* qui permet de qualifier un truc plus précis nous permettant d'aller plus loin que la simple pitrerie, pour signifier *dont l'attitude est si outrancière que sa sincérité est douteuse* (TLFi) :

> ...et ils se livrent à de telles simagrées ?
>  ...et ils nous
>   opposent leur (petite) politique patriotique de cirque ?